# Why does my machine only get 180Mbps on a Gigabit ethernet network?

Tags: networking, ethernet, connection, gigabit-ethernet

I have a network topology similar to the diagram below:

[image]

My PC was a custom build, by a company that does custom PC's. It s/has/had top of the line components for the most part. My PC would be PC 1 in the diagram.

My wife's computer, PC3, is an MSI laptop which is decent. Not a major gaming machine by any means, but it can do its thing.

The Managed switches in my network are, effectively, daisy chained on a Gigabit network. Every port reflects a Gigabit connection.

**The problem is, my machine - gets only 170Mbps at the BEST**

This has been verified by speedtest.net, speakeasy.net/speedtest and fast.com. All report a speed of roughly 160-180Mbps.

My wife's computer, which is technically one more hop downstream from mine, gets 960-980Mbps without fail. EVERY TIME.

I am at my wits end, I do not know what is causing my machine such slow speeds. I have all Cat6 cable throughout my house, with a select few devices using Cat5e (Garage door module, energy module, furnace, other home automation stuff)

What can I possibly look for to upgrade on my machine? My current Mobo is an Asus ROG STRIX Z370-H with an onboard Intel I219-V Ethernet Controller.

If there is anything else of significance I can provide, let me know and I will update this question. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I should also add, that my intranetwork transfer is also capped at 180Mbps

**UPDATE**

In an attempt to further debug, I installed a linux VM on this box. It used its own network interface mapped to the physical nic  used here. I ran a speed test using iperf and another tool. Both reported speeds of 760-890 Mbps. The windows host was still limited to 170Mbps.

This obviously is related to a restriction within windows. But what? What could I look for that could be restricting this?

Comment: have you tried testing your computer on the same switch/drop your wife is currently using? are any other network processes administered by your machine?

Comment: Yes, Same result.

Comment: Try a point to point connection with your wife's computer, maybe?

Comment: Do you have any firewall software (other than Windows of course) installed? Do you have any network optimization software installed and/or tweaked network settings according to some guide? Did you try using a Live Linux yet? What operating systems are in play?

Comment: have you tried a different network adapter to rule out hardware? Have you tried updating/reinstalling drivers? As others have said, do you have any firewall software that may be causing problems/limiting the bandwidth?

Comment: Windows 10 on both machines, no different network adapters to try - have tried reinstalling drivers. No firewalls are currently enabled

Comment: slight chance you may have some success with disabling/reconfiguring some of the advanced properties on your Ethernet adapter - just google "optimize network adapter settings" for some suggestions. if it doesn't help an uninstall/reinstall will revert everything back to defaults anyway.

Comment: Optimizing the nic did nothing. Driver reinstalls also yielded nothing remarkable. The Linux vm worked with flying colors using the same hardware. The problem definitely lies within windows.

Comment: Have you tried iperf within Windows? Would be interesting to see if UDP is faster than TCP. There are many ways to tune TCP. Also, try either direction (swap the send/recv ends). And try between Windows and the VM in a host-only network to rule out the physical adapter and its settings.